# PHP pass by reference bug?

Tags: php, debugging, pass-by-reference

Don't pass by reference. I know..... but.

Can anyone explain what is going on here?  I will try to explain what I think is going and maybe it's a PHP bug.

The code script below shows an example where an array of strings is passed by reference (I know don't...), and the string is changed if equal to a flag.

The array comes out of that `foreach` loop intact.  The string has been changed as desired.  All other values are still in the array.

I pass the altered array **not by reference** into another foreach loop and try to simply push the values onto another array (`$other_array`) using the same variable name as used in the first loop.  I assume the variable name would be reset to the new value (similar to $variable = "new value").  However, it seems the variable name is not de-referenced.

Somehow in that loop, the original array is altered and comes out with a duplicate second last value, and missing the original last value. This is always true for other cases with longer more complex arrays.

The code is below that someone can verify this.

1) Is this a PHP bug, that the variable is not de-ferenced when being used in the second `foreach` loop?

2) If anyone can supply information about what may be going on under the hood of PHP in terms of referencing variables, I would be happy to understand. In other words, why does foreach cause a duplicate and missing element on the array?

```
<?php


$array = ["one", "two", "three"];
$other_array = [];
echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
echo "</pre>";

foreach($array as &$reference){
  if($reference == "one") $reference = "one_changed";
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
echo "</pre>";

foreach($array as $reference){
  array_push($other_array, $reference);
}
echo "====changed them but did not push onto array====<br>";

echo "====changed also====";
echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
echo "</pre>";
echo "====changed also====";
echo "<pre>";
print_r($other_array);
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a bug, if you want to reuse variable previously used as reference, you need to do this:

```php
unset($var);
```

Specifically, adding this one line after your first loop:

```php
foreach($array as &$reference){
  if($reference == "one") $reference = "one_changed";
}
unset($reference); // <--- this
```

Resolves all problems:

```
Array
(
    [0] => one
    [1] => two
    [2] => three
)
Array
(
    [0] => one_changed
    [1] => two
    [2] => three
)
====changed them but did not push onto array====<br>====changed also====Array
(
    [0] => one_changed
    [1] => two
    [2] => three
)
====changed also====Array
(
    [0] => one_changed
    [1] => two
    [2] => three
)
```

And one more thing. Array elements also can be references, e.g.:

```php
$a = 1;

$c=[];
$c[0] =& $a;
$c[1] =& $a;
print_r($c);

$a=2;
print_r($c);
```

That will output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 1
)
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 2
)
```

So, to explain what exactly going on in your code... I'd rather pass. You make a referenced loop variable, then you use it as non-referenced variable in another loop and push it as a value in other array... Screw it, I give up.

Answer (score 0):

This is not "pass by reference" as there is no passing here.

Modifying array elements in a `foreach` loop with `&` is described in the [PHP manual page on foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php), with a warning about needing to unset the variable afterwards.

> Warning
>
> Reference of a $value and the last array element remain even after the
>   foreach loop. It is recommended to destroy it by unset(). Otherwise
>   you will experience the following behavior: